# Not able to open Hive query result file 000000_0

Tags: ubuntu, hive, file-type

I have created a table in hive and filled the data into table.(json data using json serde).
I am able to get the result of the queries on the console.
like:

```
select user from mytable....
```

now I saved the result of query as comma separated file using the following command:

```
set hive.io.output.fileformat = CSVTextFile;
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/host/Hadoop/' select user,task from my table
```

A file `000000_0` is getting created at the location `/host/Hadoop` but when I am clicking on the file to open it is showing error

```
could not display file /host/Hadoop/000000_0 unknown type.
```

Cann't I open this file? Is there any other way to open this file?
(I am using Ubuntu 12.04 OS)

Answer (score 1):

you can also give a try to use a custom [CSV SerDe](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) which uses OpenCSV to parse the files
Also, The problem is that HIVE does not allow you to specify the output delimiter - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-634

The solution is to create external table for output (with delimiter specification) and insert overwrite table instead of directory.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably Ubuntu relies on the file extension to determine how to open the file. Your file doesn't have one, so Ubuntu doesn't know what program to use. To fix this, either specify a program explicitly (e.g., by running `less /host/Hadoop/000000_0` to open it with `less`), or rename the file with an extension that Ubuntu recognizes (e.g., `/host/Hadoop/000000_0.txt`).

Comment: Thanks Ruakh,using less I am able to see the output but it is showing ^A seperated instead of comma seperated..Any idea for this?

Comment: Instead of using INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY, create the output table (specify the delimiters) and use INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE